# Get Data from Rss Feed to power BI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, rss-reader

Is it possible to connect to an RSS feed? I'd like to make use of the data insurance company in Amman stock exchange, which is available as a daily feed

https://www.ase.com.jo/en/company_historical/MDGF

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI desktop, you just need to click **Get data-> Other-> web** and provide the URL there, every time the data is update, you will get the latest values.